# How to return the X greatest rows for each row in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume I have two tables(below). What is the best way to write a select to get the 2 employees with the highest salary from each department? Assume that there are potentially a lot of departments.

output:

```
employee_name | salary | department_id
John          | 65000  | 1
Sally         | 60000  | 1
Lucy          | 40000  | 2
James         | 80000  | 3
Harry         | 65000  | 3
```

Tables:

**Employee**

```
employee_name | salary | department_id
John          | 65000  | 1
Sally         | 60000  | 1
Connor        | 55000  | 1
Judy          | 55000  | 1
Lucy          | 40000  | 2
James         | 80000  | 3
Harry         | 65000  | 3
Penny         | 56000  | 3
```

**Department**

```
department_id | name
1             | Sales
2             | Marketing
3             | IT
```

Comment: Which version of SQL server do You use?

Comment: I'm not fixed to a certain version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best for such type of selects is `OUTER APPLY`. It is designed for this type of work:

```
select d.department_id, oa.employee_name, oa.salary
from Departments d
outer apply(select top 2 e.employee_name, e.salary 
            from Employee e 
            where d.department_id = e.department_id 
            order by e.salary desc) oa
```

If you don't want to get departments where there are no employees then just change `outer apply` to `cross apply`

Comment: I haven't seen that one before, exactly what I was looking for! It is quite a readable syntax too! nice one!

Comment: So it looks like CROSS APPLY is essentially the INNER JOIN whereas OUTER APPLY (in the answer) is the OUTER JOIN version.

Comment: So the way i'm reading the documentation on CROSS APPLY is that it selects everything on the left (Department) and then for each row it runs the select right side. Is that how you think about it?

Comment: @FuzzyJulz, I think of it like: loop through all rows in left table and then for each row select something from apply sybquery and do a join of one row from left and result for this row from right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` like this.

```
;WITH CTE as
(
SELECT employee_name,Salary,department_id,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY department_id ORDER BY Salary DESC) rn
FROM Employee
)
SELECT employee_name,Salary,d.department_id,d.name
FROM CTE c
INNER JOIN Departments d ON d.department_id = c.department_id
WHERE rn <= 2
```

Comment: You should mension the this way he will not get all departments, if for example there are no employees yet.

Comment: yes you are correct, but OP expects output to contain employee name as well, so i think he means to get departments with employees only.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/377f7/1 - I've started writing same example, but since, you posted the answer first, here it is.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking departments with employees, but I am fine either way.

Comment: Well, actually Giorgi Nakeuri was first. and his answer is correct as well. You can mark any answer which suits you and solved your problem. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/377f7/8

Answer (score 1):

This `CTE` method is quite efficient
Use This Code:

```
Create  TABLE #table
(
    name varchar(10),
    salary varchar(10),
    depid int

)

insert into #table values('John','65000',1)
insert into #table values('Sally','60000',1)
insert into #table values('Connor','55000',1)
insert into #table values('Judy','55000',1)
insert into #table values('Lucy','65000',2)
insert into #table values('Kevin','55000',2)
insert into #table values('Ram','60000',2)
insert into #table values('James','80000',3)
insert into #table values('Harry','65000',3)
insert into #table values('Penny','56000',3)

select * from #table


;With CTE as
(
select name,salary,depid,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by depid order by salary desc) as maxisal from #table
)
select name,salary,depid from CTE
where maxisal<=2
```

EDIT: changed maxi to maxisal to get it to work - Fuzzyjulz

**Note:i have added two entries for Depid 2**

**Output:**

```
name    salary  depid   
John    65000   1        
Sally   60000   1        
Lucy    65000   2        
Ram     60000   2        
James   80000   3        
Harry   65000   3
```